# Better way to make a certain list with palindromic sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, palindrome

Here is my code, which works, but seems a little too long, I think might be a more refined version.

```
Range[Ceiling[#/2]] ~ Join ~ 
  If[OddQ[#], Rest, Identity] @ Reverse @ Range[Ceiling[#/2]] & /@ Range[9]

Range[Ceiling[#/2]] ~ Join ~ Range[Floor[#/2], 1, -1] & /@ Range[9]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 3,  2, 1}, 
>  {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Can I ask downvoters about the reason? I do not claim they have no reason, I just can't see any now.

Comment: @kuba Perhaps it's the Anti-Infix-Police?

Comment: @cormullion so we do not like Infix here? :) I was not aware of that

Comment: Talking of infix `~Join~` - innumerable times I've pondered why Mathematica doesn't have a better infix shorthand for it. There's `<>` for `StringJoin`, after all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Table[Min[i, n + 1 - i], {n, 9}, {i, n}]
```

Comment: This is much more intuitive than mine! :)

Answer (score 7):

The question is in my opinion more about math than Mathematica and so is my answer (unless the goal is to create these lists through specific constructs), but here it is nonetheless:

```
Table[(1 + x - Abs[1 - 2 n + x]) / 2, {x, 9}, {n, x}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Although I think Ray Koopman's method is the way to go, I cannot pass on pointing out the similarity to [`TriangleWave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TriangleWave.html), therefore:

```
Table[n/2 TriangleWave[i/2/n], {n, 2, 10}, {i, n - 1}] // Simplify
```

> ```
> {{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1},
>  {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}}
> ```

`Simplify` is needed because `TriangleWave` does not fully evaluate in some cases without it.

Answer (score 2):

```
# + 1 - Abs@Range[-#, #] & /@ ((Range@9 - 1)/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the heck of it, a *recursive* solution:

```
f[1] = {1};
f[n_] := f[n] = With[{list = f[n - 1]},
    If[EvenQ[n - 1],
     Insert[list, 1 + list[[(n - 1)/2]], (n + 1)/2],
     Insert[list, list[[n/2]], 1 + n/2]]
    ];

Table[f[k], {k, 1, 10}]
```

!!!