# Efficient way to build a certain square matrix

Tags: matrix, algorithm, expression-construction

For odd `n` I'm looking for a short and swift way to construct with (f.e.)

```
n = 3
```

[image]

```
n = 11
```

[image]

```
n=1111
```

[image]

Comment: How come the question got fewer upvotes than it received answers? It should have at least that number (plus one).

Comment: @Jens ......... Why?

Comment: @eldo Well, if one deems a question worthy of answering, then it should probably be worthy of an upvote too.  I upvote questions I answer almost always, though I often forget to do it right away, so the upvote may come only an hour after the answer.  This is a question that clearly interests people and they're having fun with it.

Comment: Related link: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32307/better-way-to-make-a-certain-list-with-palindromic-sublists

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's my take using `NestList`

```
cm[n_] := NestList[# + 1 &, Join[Range[n/2 + 1], Reverse@Range[n/2]], n - 1]
```

Then

```
cm[11]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's a `FoldList` version (just as fast):

```
cmf[n_] := FoldList[#1 + #2 &, Join[Range[n/2 + 1], Reverse@Range[n/2]], 
            ConstantArray[1, n - 1]]
```

The above methods according to the benchmarks posted are already as fast as the fastest methods. Here's a method that's just as fast as Belisarius's (I took a page from his rule based solution):

```
a4[n_] := With[{t = Join[Range[n/2 + 1], Reverse@Range[n/2]]}, Array[s + # &, n, 0] /. s -> t]
```

**Timings:**

I have taken the fastest methods from the five answers with the fastest times and for each function I averaged 7 runs per input for 9 different sizes (1001 to 9001), here are the results:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

After working with JacobAkerbbom to get his `LibraryLink` method working on Windows [see here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15584/discussion-between-runnykine-and-jacob-akkerboom), I've now included his method which obviously is now the king of the hill.

Comment: @Give my *frx* update a whirl on large *n* if you have the time...

Comment: @rasher, that's the one I included in this latest update. The `f6` was slightly slower than Szabolcs`.

Comment: No, I mean the one called *FRX* - just added it ;-)

Comment: @rasher, I knew when you added it and I immediately tested and updated my plot.

Comment: @rasher Like I said `frx` is slightly faster than Szabolcs` wheras `f6` was slightly slower.

Comment: Interesting - consistently beats others on large n on my tests - the vagaries of benchmarking I suppose - f6 won for realistic *n* on *Szabolcs*' tests... but they're all pretty fast!

Comment: If you still have your data, maybe you can add my timings to your answer? (+1)

Comment: Also, note that `Range[1000000, 1, -1]` is faster than `Reverse@Range[1000000]`.

Answer (score 12):

*Edit: See end of post for latest performance enhancement.*

```
f=With[{c = Ceiling[#/2]}, c - 1 + Array[#1 - Abs[c - #2] &, {#, #}]] &;

f[5]

(* {{1, 2, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 3, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 4, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 6, 5}} *)
```

Short, sweet, fast.

For more speed,

```
f5 = With[{c = Ceiling[#/2]},
   Subtract[
    ArrayPad[ConstantArray[Range[#, # + c - 1], c], {{c - 1, 0}, {0, c - 1}}, "Reflected"], 
    Range[# - 1, 0, -1]]] &
```

And even faster...

```
f6[n_] := ConstantArray[Join[Range[n/2 + 1], Reverse@Range[n/2]], n] + Range[0, n - 1]
```

Update: For large *n*, this seems to do quite well (takes a hit for smallish *n* before auto-compile kicks in, could just compile overall):

```
frx[n_] := With[{rng = Range@(n + Floor[n/2]),fl = Floor[n/2], r = Range@n},
   Table[Join[rng[[x ;; x + fl]], rng[[Subtract[x + fl, 1] ;; x ;; -1]]], {x, r}]];
```

Finally, if this is something you're going to call repeatedly with varying *n*, particulary larger *n*, consider injecting a precomputed base of maximum needed size into a lookup function (see later fastest only benchmark for performance illustration):

```
x2 = With[{base = fr[5001]}, Drop[base, # + 1 ;;, {Ceiling[#/2] + 1, -Ceiling[#/2]}] &];
```

As requested, a quick bench chart. Usual loungebook caveats apply, and I did not include *nasser*'s or *aky*'s, both get slow on large problems. Looks like `f6` and *Runnykine*`s solutions trade blows for fastest. Update: I'd spaced on *Szabolc*'s answer, added it - seems it and F6 vie for fastest (I'd write off differences to noise), both having a *slight* but consistent edge over *Runnykine*'s solution (and that itself is small).

Update 2: Added *belisarius*' second method. Quite quick!

[image]

Here's a new set of benchmarks of just the fastest few. Note I've used `Timing` vs `AbsoluteTiming` - I think this a much better indicator of efficiency for this kind of test. That said, the earlier ones seemed pretty consistent with *Szabolcs*' benchmarks, so beyond platform / version / `AbsoluteTiming` clouding things, *hypothesis non fingo* why *Runnykine*'s benchmarks seem to differ significantly. Times are average of ten runs per size per tested.

Code I used for this Q-N-D:

```
tested = {x2,f6, frx, szabolcs, belisaurius2, runnykinea4};
times = 10;
cur = {}
Monitor[
 fastestBmark = 
  Table[cur = {size, (Mean[
         Table[(ClearSystemCache[]; 
           First@Timing@(#@size)), {times}]]) & /@ tested}, {size, 
    301, 5101, 200}], cur]
```

[image]

Finally (really...), one can extend the latter idea if the need is repeated calls over a wide range of *n* by caching "touchstone" base cases and using the appropriate case for a given *n* (since dropping has overhead inverse to amount dropped - one could also switch between `Drop` and `Part` depending on *n* vs touchstone size):

```
x3 = With[{base = 
     frx[#] & /@ {101, 301, 501, 701, 1001, 2001, 3001, 4001, 5001}}, 
   With[{p = Position[{101, 301, 501, 701, 1001, 2001, 3001, 4001, 5001}, 
                       x_ /; x >= #, 1, 1] &@#}, 
     If[p == {}, {}, 
          Drop[base[[p[[1, 1]]]], # + 1 ;;, {Ceiling[#/2] + 1, -Ceiling[#/2]}]]] &];
```

Here's a quick test against the fastest answer excluding my others:

[image]

Comment: We posted nearly the same thing at almost the same time.

Comment: @Szabolcs: LOL, like minds. I recently posted and answer that was *exactly* the same as one by *Mr. Wizard*. We got a chuckle, he posted a hilarious GIF reply. +1 on yours, of course ;-)

Comment: @rasher All the answers so far are much nicer than the ugly code with which I produced the question. Yesterday, you made this logarithmic ("Ferrari") speed test. It would certainly facilitate my acceptance of one of the answers if you would ran "Ferrari" again against this case.

Comment: I feel left out from the chart :(  On my machine my solution is faster than either `f6` or RunnyKine's solution, by a tiny margin.  Algorithmically it's the same as your `f`, but for some reason it's the fastest in my benchmarking.  Probably because `Table` auto-compiles, while `Array` (probably) doesn't.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yeah - I spaced on your answer - updating now. I'd venture parallelizing could be interesting, can't test - cigar smoking and on loungebook...

Comment: Do you mind to use my second try on the comparison?

Comment: @belisarius: Sure, I'd be happy to, a bit busy right now, but will do soon...

Comment: @belisarius: Added. Nicely done. +1

Comment: @rasher Thanks! I still don't fully get why a replace is so fast

Comment: Updated my benchmarks too a bit.  It's very clear now that `f6` is well ahead for small (i.e. practical) `n`.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for update - this is one of those trivial yet interesting problems, fun for working the brain. I've got an idea that might be even faster... need to get some eats first...

Comment: @Szabolcs: IF you have the time/moivation, give *frx* a whirl for large *n* - seems to do quite well on loungebook tests (as a rule I don't use my real machines for goofing off, so only tested to limits on toy machine).

Comment: See my updated `Array` based method.

Comment: @rasher I'm using a different computer now (desktop).  `f6` vs `szabolcs` vs `frx` gives 0.51 vs 0.41 vs 0.24 seconds with `Min@Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[frx[5001];], {5}]`.  `frx` is the fastest.  Will benchmark more tomorrow, no time today.

Comment: There are so many answers already that I won't bother writing one, but I would expect that the absolute fastest way to do it would be to preallocate the matrix, generate a single `Range`, and copy spans from that into the matrix (row-wise, of course, unless we want to do it in Fortran). Actually, there isn't anything too complicated about this, so LibraryLink could be used to help the branch predictor and prefetcher work their magic.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I like that you mentioned branch prediction. I actually made an answer based on LibraryLink, but not copying from a single range, which I think is a good idea. When you naively copy elements, this does not save on branches, you are replacing tests like "plus one or minus one?" by "am I at the end of the copy range?". But I suppose memcpy (or something similar) must handle inlining/branch prediction very well, limiting such tests. I suppose there may be other benefits as well, but here my limited understanding of the internals of the computer kick in.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom copying elements helps in the sense that the branch is between copying another (continuing the loop) and stopping (exiting the loop). Doing it another way will introduce extra conditionals and special cases that result in more mispredicts. Of course we want to keep the source range in L1 cache, while writing an entire cache line at a time prevents cache thrashing. And the memory access predictor only deals with quite simple access patterns, so it may not work if we do non-consecutive accesses.

Answer (score 11):

This is pretty straightforward and very easy to follow even for someone who just started learning Mathematica.  This has its value when you need to read your code a year later, even if you're an experienced user.

```
n = 11;
k = (n + 1)/2;
row = k - Abs[k - Range[n]];
Table[row + i, {i, 0, n - 1}]
```

Should be fast enough for most application.

---

#### Benchmarks

**The timings from the plot below are outdated.  Several people have posted faster versions since, but I haven't had time to update the plot.**  I'll keep the benchmark code below in case someone wants to experiment with it.

```
nasser[n_] := Module[{mid},
  mid = Ceiling[n/2];
  SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j > mid, {i_, j_} /; j <= mid} :> {n - j + 
      i, i + j - 1}, {n, n}]
  ]

kuba1[n_] :=     
 ArrayPad[HankelMatrix[Range@n, 
    Range[n, n + Floor[n/2]]][[;; , ;; Ceiling[n/2]]], {{0, 0}, {0, 
    Floor[n/2]}}, "Reflected"]

kuba2[n_] := 
 ArrayPad[Array[Range[#, # + Floor[n/2]] &, n], {{0, 0}, {0, Floor[n/2]}}, "Reflected"]


kuba3[n_] := 
 Transpose[Range[n] + # & /@ Join[#, #[[-2 ;; 1 ;; -1]]] &@Range[0, Floor[n/2]]]

rasher1 = 
 With[{c = Ceiling[#/2]}, c - 1 + Array[#1 - Abs[c - #2] &, {#, #}]] &


rasher5 = 
  With[{c = Ceiling[#/2]}, 
    Subtract[
     ArrayPad[
      ConstantArray[Range[#, # + c - 1], c], {{c - 1, 0}, {0, c - 1}},
       "Reflected"], Range[# - 1, 0, -1]]] &;

rasher6[n_] := 
 ConstantArray[Join[Range[n/2 + 1], Reverse@Range[n/2]], n] + 
  Range[0, n - 1]

belisarius[n_] := (Join[#, Rest@Reverse@#] &@Range[n/2 + 1]) + # & /@ Range[0, n - 1]

belisarius2[n_] := With[{k = (Join[#, Rest@Reverse@#] &@Range[n/2 + 1])}, s + Range[0, n - 1] /. s -> k]

algohi[n_] := 
 Module[{k},
  k = Table[i, {i, 1 + #, n + #}] & /@ Range[0, n/2]; 
  Transpose@Join[Most@k, Reverse@k]
 ]

runnykine[n_] := 
 NestList[# + 1 &, Join[Range[n/2 + 1], Reverse@Range[n/2]], n - 1]

szabolcs[n_] := 
 Module[{k, row},
  k = (n + 1)/2;
  row = k - Abs[k - Range[n]];
  Table[row + i, {i, 0, n - 1}]
 ]
```

Verify they all do what they should:

```
functions = {"nasser", "kuba1", "kuba2", "kuba3", "rasher1", "rasher5", "rasher6", "belisarius", "belisarius2", "algohi", "runnykine", "szabolcs"};

Equal @@ Through[(ToExpression /@ functions)[11]]
(* True *)
```

Benchmark, be careful to choose odd `n` values only:

```
bench[fun_String] := 
 Module[{f = ToExpression[fun]}, 
  Table[{n, Min@Table[First@AbsoluteTiming[f[n]], {3}]}, {n, 2 Round[2^Range[4, 11, 1/2]] + 1}]
]

results = bench /@ functions;

ListLogLogPlot[results, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {10^-5, 1}, PlotLegends -> functions, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> colours]
```

[image]

Observe how both my and Algohi's solution gets a sudden boost at a certain size threshold.  This is due to `Table` automatically compiling its argument above `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength"]`.

Further speedups are certainly possible by manually compiling some of the other solutions.

---

Numerical `results` from my machine, so you don't have to re-run it if you just want to re-plot it.

Caveat: This was run on a laptop.  Laptop CPUs have the habit of throttling their frequency when they heat up, which may affect results.

```
{{{33, 0.006806}, {47, 0.008816}, {65, 0.013106}, {91, 
   0.022375}, {129, 0.044451}, {183, 0.096939}, {257, 0.196829}, {363,
    0.413977}, {513, 0.885362}, {725, 1.889206}, {1025, 
   4.141960}, {1449, 9.229286}, {2049, 20.484070}, {2897, 
   47.915846}, {4097, 123.148882}}, {{33, 0.000029}, {47, 
   0.000046}, {65, 0.000079}, {91, 0.000140}, {129, 0.000270}, {183, 
   0.000531}, {257, 0.001022}, {363, 0.002025}, {513, 0.004224}, {725,
    0.008757}, {1025, 0.019102}, {1449, 0.039411}, {2049, 
   0.078217}, {2897, 0.153589}, {4097, 0.338157}}, {{33, 
   0.000081}, {47, 0.000115}, {65, 0.000159}, {91, 0.000229}, {129, 
   0.000351}, {183, 0.000594}, {257, 0.002159}, {363, 0.004096}, {513,
    0.008323}, {725, 0.016285}, {1025, 0.035317}, {1449, 
   0.070283}, {2049, 0.149849}, {2897, 0.288016}, {4097, 
   0.607098}}, {{33, 0.000096}, {47, 0.000136}, {65, 0.000194}, {91, 
   0.000294}, {129, 0.000477}, {183, 0.000937}, {257, 0.001827}, {363,
    0.003632}, {513, 0.007367}, {725, 0.014935}, {1025, 
   0.034238}, {1449, 0.066544}, {2049, 0.135146}, {2897, 
   0.267405}, {4097, 0.665833}}, {{33, 0.000211}, {47, 0.000402}, {65,
    0.000751}, {91, 0.001488}, {129, 0.002925}, {183, 0.005780}, {257,
    0.011469}, {363, 0.022900}, {513, 0.045602}, {725, 
   0.091659}, {1025, 0.185086}, {1449, 0.370420}, {2049, 
   0.745876}, {2897, 1.493142}, {4097, 3.090481}}, {{33, 
   0.000041}, {47, 0.000070}, {65, 0.000123}, {91, 0.000231}, {129, 
   0.000453}, {183, 0.000896}, {257, 0.001742}, {363, 0.003533}, {513,
    0.006994}, {725, 0.013959}, {1025, 0.029870}, {1449, 
   0.059805}, {2049, 0.120957}, {2897, 0.242442}, {4097, 
   0.567620}}, {{33, 0.000023}, {47, 0.000033}, {65, 0.000054}, {91, 
   0.000090}, {129, 0.000155}, {183, 0.000297}, {257, 0.000567}, {363,
    0.001158}, {513, 0.002287}, {725, 0.005820}, {1025, 
   0.013108}, {1449, 0.025564}, {2049, 0.051499}, {2897, 
   0.100180}, {4097, 0.319559}}, {{33, 0.000198}, {47, 0.000282}, {65,
    0.000398}, {91, 0.000582}, {129, 0.000879}, {183, 0.001349}, {257,
    0.002032}, {363, 0.003323}, {513, 0.005294}, {725, 
   0.008768}, {1025, 0.016870}, {1449, 0.030577}, {2049, 
   0.082289}, {2897, 0.154232}, {4097, 0.285149}}, {{33, 
   0.000086}, {47, 0.000120}, {65, 0.000168}, {91, 0.000249}, {129, 
   0.000392}, {183, 0.000618}, {257, 0.001007}, {363, 0.001706}, {513,
    0.002993}, {725, 0.005540}, {1025, 0.011265}, {1449, 
   0.021607}, {2049, 0.068486}, {2897, 0.128332}, {4097, 
   0.242391}}, {{33, 0.000112}, {47, 0.000175}, {65, 0.000286}, {91, 
   0.000493}, {129, 0.000909}, {183, 0.001677}, {257, 0.001292}, {363,
    0.002553}, {513, 0.005325}, {725, 0.011771}, {1025, 
   0.028106}, {1449, 0.055791}, {2049, 0.110606}, {2897, 
   0.217962}, {4097, 0.534833}}, {{33, 0.000074}, {47, 0.000108}, {65,
    0.000138}, {91, 0.000206}, {129, 0.000188}, {183, 0.000375}, {257,
    0.000625}, {363, 0.001197}, {513, 0.002524}, {725, 
   0.006462}, {1025, 0.014223}, {1449, 0.027980}, {2049, 
   0.056060}, {2897, 0.111271}, {4097, 0.342107}}, {{33, 
   0.000087}, {47, 0.000109}, {65, 0.000152}, {91, 0.000204}, {129, 
   0.000330}, {183, 0.000533}, {257, 0.000695}, {363, 0.001227}, {513,
    0.002388}, {725, 0.006340}, {1025, 0.013557}, {1449, 
   0.025133}, {2049, 0.047835}, {2897, 0.094955}, {4097, 0.262013}}}
```

Comment: Do you mind to use my second try on the comparison?

Comment: @belisarius Done.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason my machine hangs running your test suite.

Comment: @belisarius It seems to use a fair bit of memory ... the monitor goes to 75% and I have 16 GB.  Updated now with more reliable results (minimum of 3 runs).  That's it for now, even though there could be plenty of improvements ... it's not really worth it.  It takes a lot of time to run.

Comment: Nicely done ....+1

Answer (score 10):

```
n = 11;
mid = Ceiling[n/2];
mat = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j > mid, {i_, j_} /; j <= mid}:>{n-j+i,i+j-1}, {n, n}];

MatrixForm@mat
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

```
b[n_] := (Join[#, Rest@Reverse@#] &@Range[n/2 + 1]) + # & /@ Range[0, n-1]
b[11] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Enhanced for some speedup, and curiously enough, it competes well with the fastest answers so far (see @rasher's benchamrk):

```
bs[n_] := With[{k = (Join[#, Rest@Reverse@#] &@Range[n/2 + 1])},  s+Range[0, n-1] /.s-> k]
```

Comment: Please see my update. It's now just neck and neck with yours and I took a page from your rule based approach.

Comment: @RunnyKine Ha! Replacements are usually quite _slow_ artifacts, I still don't understand why they beat "better" approaches here :)

Comment: My guess is that since we use a symbol the addition is not done and all the lists are generated with no computation done. Once the replacement is made a fast vector operation happens almost concertedly giving the speed-up.

Answer (score 8):

```
n = 11;
k = Table[i, {i, 1 + #, n + #}] & /@ Range[0, n/2];
(Transpose@Join[Most@k, Reverse@k]) // TableForm
```

or

```
n = 11;
Table[j, {i, 1, 
   n}, {j, (n - 1)/2 - Abs[Range[-(n - 1)/2, (n - 1)/2]] + 
    i}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
n = 11;
ArrayPad[
  HankelMatrix[Range@n, Range[n, n + Floor[n/2]]][[;; , ;; Ceiling[n/2]]],
  {{0, 0}, {0, Floor[n/2]}}, 
  "Reflected"]
```

or

```
ArrayPad[
  Array[Range[#, # + Floor[n/2]] &, n],
  {{0, 0}, {0, Floor[n/2]}}, 
  "Reflected"]
```

or

```
Transpose[
 Range[n] + # & /@ Join[#, #[[-2 ;; 1 ;; -1]]] &@Range[0, Floor[n/2]] 
 ]
```

Comment: +1 on use of Hankel. Started with similar idea, saw your post so would be redundant.

Comment: @rasher thanks, but it is almost the longest one :P

Answer (score 7):

Nothing special here, but as there wasn't any solution using `Outer`, I thought I'd post this:

```
With[{n = 11}, (* adjust n *)
Outer[#1 + #2 - 1 &, Range[n], Range[n/2 + 1]~Join~Reverse@Range[n/2]]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Since no answer used the `"Extrapolated"` option for `ArrayPad`, which in my opinion is very straightforward (although not as efficient as the top ones), here is my trying:

```
Clear[extrpol]
extrpol[n_?OddQ] := 
    With[{k = (n + 1)/2}, 
         ArrayPad[2 k - {# + 1, #} & @ {2, 1, 2}, k - {{2, 1}, 2}, "Extrapolated"]
        ]
```

Comment: Mine looked like `ArrayPad[# - {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, -1, 0}}, Floor[#/2] - 1, "Extrapolated"] &`, dropped idea - too slow. +1 in any case!

Comment: @rasher Thanks. On my machine, it's as fast as Kuba's first approach.

Answer (score 5):

```
g[n_] := With[{m=(n+1)/2},Table[n+j-m-Abs[m-i],{i,n},{j,n}]]
g[11]//Transpose//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
<< SymbolicC`
<< Developer`
<< CCompilerDriver`
<< CCodeGenerator`
```

Please don't mind these unnecessary abstractions.

```
type = "mint";

abstractFunctionName = "makeMatr";

mainFunctionName = abstractFunctionName <> "I_T";

argumentSingletonGetterFunctionName[type_String] := 
  StringJoin["MArgument_get", type];

getter = argumentSingletonGetterFunctionName["Integer"];

typeSpecWL = "MType_Integer";

dataGetterAbstractor[type_String] :=
 "MTensor_get" <> type <> "Data"

dataGetter = dataGetterAbstractor["Integer"];
```

Generate some SymbolicC

```
makeMatrSC =
 CFunction[
  "int",
  mainFunctionName,
  {{"WolframLibraryData", "libData"}, {"mint", 
    "Argc"}, {CPointerType["MArgument"], "Args"}, {"MArgument", "Res"}}
  ,
  CBlock[
   {
    CDeclare["int", CAssign["err", "LIBRARY_NO_ERROR"]],
    CDeclare[type, "input"],
    CDeclare["MTensor", "result"], 
    CDeclare[type, CArray["resultDimensions", 2]],

    CAssign[
     "input", 
     CCall[getter, CArray["Args", 0]]
     ],

    CAssign[CArray["resultDimensions", 0], "input"], 
    CAssign[CArray["resultDimensions", 1], "input"], 
    CAssign["err", 
     CCall[CPointerMember["libData", "MTensor_new"], {typeSpecWL, 2, 
       "resultDimensions", CAddress["result"]}]],

    CDeclare[CPointerType[type], "resultDataPtr"],
    CDeclare[type, CAssign["value", 1]],
    CDeclare[type, 
     CAssign["square", COperator[Times, {"input", "input"}]]],
    CDeclare[type, CAssign["half", COperator[Divide, {"input", 2}]]],

    CAssign["resultDataPtr", 
     CCall[CPointerMember["libData", dataGetter], {"result"}]], 
    CDeclare[type, CAssign["iter", 1]],
    CDeclare[type, CAssign["iterRest", 1]],
    CDeclare[type, 
     CAssign["inputMOne" , COperator[Minus, {"input", 1}]]],

    CWhile[
     COperator[LessEqual, {"iter", "square"}],
     CBlock[
      {
       CAssign[CDereference["resultDataPtr"], "value"],
       COperator[Increment, "resultDataPtr"],
       CIf[
        COperator[LessEqual, {"iterRest", "half"}],
        COperator[Increment, "value"],
        COperator[Decrement, "value"]
        ],
       COperator[Increment, "iter"],
       CIf[
        COperator[Equal, {"iterRest", "inputMOne" }],
        CAssign["iterRest", 0],
        COperator[Increment, "iterRest"]
        ]
       }
      ]
     ],
    CCall["MArgument_setMTensor", {"Res", "result"}],
    CReturn["err"]
    }
   ]
  ];
```

Make it into a string

```
cCodeString = "DLLEXPORT"<> " " <> ToCCodeString[makeMatrSC];

boilerPlate = "
#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

/* Return the version of Library Link */
DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
\treturn WolframLibraryVersion;
}

/* Initialize Library */
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData \
libData) {
\treturn LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

/* Uninitialize Library */
DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData \
libData) {
\treturn;
}

";

totalCString = boilerPlate <> cCodeString;
```

Create a library (code can be reused, as it makes different versions of the library. Todo: make code that cleans up libraries)

```
If[! ValueQ[counter], counter = 1;];
counter++;
counterString = ToString[counter];
libraryName = abstractFunctionName <> "Lib" <> counterString;
lib = CreateLibrary[totalCString, libraryName];
```

Load the library

```
LibraryLoad[libraryName]

makeMatrLL = 
 LibraryFunctionLoad[libraryName, 
  mainFunctionName, {{Integer}}, {Integer, 2}]
```

and profit

```
makeMatrLL[5]
```

> [image]

**Timing**

My previous timings were kind of bad. This is because `rI = (rI+1)%input` is much slower than

```
if(rI == input -1){rI = 0}else{rI++}`
```

So I guess I learned something :).

My code seems to be the fastest code in this Q&A. Below I compare with RunnyKine, but really you should see his answer for a nice graph.

Timing data

```
timeTable[func_] := 
 Table[Mean@Table[First@Timing@func[in], {5}], {in, 1001, 9001, 1000}]

timings = timeTable[makeMatrLL];
a4Timings = timeTable[a4];
{timings, a4Timings}
```

> ```
>  {{0.002772, 0.009899, 0.021801, 0.038221, 0.109890, 0.159009, 
>    0.213708, 0.284732, 0.377101}, {0.005047, 0.028429, 0.057490, 
>    0.101514, 0.152389, 0.212622, 0.293324, 0.378144, 0.418646}}
> ```

Again, see RunnyKine's answer for a nice graph :)

**Further improvements**

It seems the main thing that is unnecessary in this code is that we check the value of `restIter` at every iteration. Maybe we can assume that the input size will always be larger than a certain number. In this case, we can inline some code that many times in order to avoid "branches", i.e. using `CIf` too much. Using a bunch of `Range`s in *Mathematica* also has to deal with conditions when copying the Ranges into the big matrix. My LibraryLink code does not have to copy data, which is something normal Mathematica code cannot avoid. But it seems these conditionals take much more time than copying of data.

Finally Oleksandr made a good point that copying ranges from a single range array would probably be faster.

Comment: I was out of town, I just saw this now. will give it a spin and include the timing in my answer. +1, I was hoping someone would use `LibraryLink` since I'm not very good at it.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "LibraryFunction::libload: The function makeMatrI_T was not loaded from the file C:\Users\... when I run the `LibraryFunctionLoad`

Comment: @RunnyKine ah that is unfortunate. I suppose using CompilationTarget -> "C" in Compile does work for you? I hear it can be a bit tricky under Windows.

Comment: Yes that works for me in `Compile`

Comment: @RunnyKine hmm, maybe WolframLibrary.h has to be put in some include folder that the compiler can find. You can find WolframLibrary.h here: `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "IncludeFiles", "C", "WolframLibrary.h"}]`. Alternatively, you can convert the `cCodeString` into a file and put WolframLibrary.h in the same folder.

Comment: Note that you can use `CreateLibrary` on a file (see docs).

Comment: I'm not getting any success and I need to hit the sack now. Will get back to this later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15584/discussion-between-runnykine-and-jacob-akkerboom).